# Is there something obviously wrong here that's slowing my code (nested loops) down?

Tags: r, performance, loops

I know it's a StackOverflow sin to not create a reproducible example, but I'm not sure it's necessary in this. The following nested loop takes 40 minutes to run. There are ~6,300 rows in ptptdata, which represents an individual. The loop just pulls someone's age and duration until retirement. It runs a loop that adds inflation (taken from infdata) and merit growth (static 2.5%) until duration. Once the loop ends, it saves the final salary and age back to ptptdata. It then moves down a row to the next individual and does it again. I've read that using a vector instead of adding back to ptptdata would be faster, but I'm not sure I'm following how to do that. I was expecting the code to be slow, but I have a lot more to add to this and it won't be feasible if this simple process is taking this long.

```
ptptdata$FinalSalary <- 0
ptptdata$FinalAge <- 0
trial <- 1


    for(row in 1:nrow(ptptdata)){ ### Tells model to complete loop for each individual
      i <- 1 ## Starting point for each individual
      dur <- as.numeric(ptptdata[row,"DurationRet"]) 
      age <- as.numeric(ptptdata[row, "Age"])
      salary <- as.numeric(ptptdata[row,"Current Salary"])
      
      while (i<=dur){
        inflation <- as.numeric(infdata[infdata$Item == 'Inflation' & infdata$Scenario == as.factor(trial),i+2])
        salboy <- salary
        ageboy <- age
        salary <- salboy * (1+meritgrowth)* (1+inflation)
        age <- age + 1
        i <- i + 1  
      }
       ptptdata[row,"FinalSalary"]<-salary
       ptptdata[row,"FinalAge"]<-age
      }
```

Comment: I've never used R, but it looks to me like you're doing all your math on string data, and you're also doing string comparisons in your inner-most loop.  Wouldn't it be better to extract the relevant data as a numeric vector / matrix and operate on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ptptdata$FinalSalary <- 0
ptptdata$FinalAge <- 0
trial <- 1

durv <- as.numeric(ptptdata$DurationRet)
agev <- as.numeric(ptptdata$Age)
salaryv <- as.numeric(ptptdata[['Current Salary']])

xx <- infdata$Item == 'Inflation' & infdata$Scenario == as.factor(trial)

for(row in 1:nrow(ptptdata)) {
  i <- 1 
  dur <- durv[row]
  age <- agev[row]
  salary <- salaryv[row]
  
  while (i<=dur){
    inflation <- as.numeric(infdata[[i+2]][xx])
    salboy <- salary
    ageboy <- age
    salary <- salboy * (1+meritgrowth)* (1+inflation)
    age <- age + 1
    i <- i + 1  
  }
  ptptdata[row,"FinalSalary"]<-salary
  ptptdata[row,"FinalAge"]<-age
}
```

maybe this will be faster...